# Retrieve Private Key for the generated CSR

Tags: c#, windows, keystore, private-key, csr

I am create CSR using certenroll object.
Primary key is created on the same machine(Ccertificate store).

How to retrieve primary key which is stored on local store for the CSR generated.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the private key from [X509Certificate2.PrivateKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.privatekey.aspx).

```
var store = new X509Store (StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

var thumbprint = "AA99202885098B541C1ECD09C85351ED084A4A12";
var certificate = store.Certificates.Find (X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false) [0];

var privateKey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider) certificate.PrivateKey;
```

Also, X509Certificate offers methods to export as various formats including pfx.